# Wifi gets disconnected when connecting to VPN via Cisco AnyConnect Client

Tags: wifi, vpn

I have a Macbook Pro 2017 model. Whenever I try to connect to VPN via Cisco AnyConnect Client, my wifi gets disconnected. I have to again restart my router and try with the Cisco client again. In 2-3 attempts I do get connected to the VPN. But till I get connected, I have to retry the steps and manually restart my router. How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Hello. I have a Cisco ASA installed at my site and I'm using the Cisco AnyConnect Mac client (4.9.06037, the last version for today). And I noticed that my Macbook gets reconnects to WiFi from time to time. This only happens if AnyConnect is connected. In the case of another VPN client (native IKEv2) that isn't reproduced. I thought it was WiFi (I'm sitting right under the AP), but it looks like this is not the case. Do you have any new discoveries in this matter? MacBook Pro 2018, macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Answer (score 1):

I had several clients that this problem.  Cisco AnyConnect can fail to connect if your router is misconfigured. The only way this was cured was by contacting the Internet Service Provider and having them reconfigure the router from their end to enable VPN connections to succeed.